# Customizing file link in Drupal7 template

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I'm creating a custom layout (node--article.tpl.php) for a custom content type based on the Article type supplied in the base Drupal7 install.  All I've added is a file attachment field for a PDF file.

I want to have a link in the rendered page that says something like ("PDF Version").  I've created a template file for that content type and it's working ok.  I've used the `print render($content['field_pdf']);` code snippet to display the file link.  It shows as the file's name as a link to the file with a PDF icon beside it.  Almost perfect!

I just need to change the file's name to the static string "PDF Version".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [hook_node_view_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7)()

```
function yourmodule_node_view_alter(&$build)
{
    $node = $build['#node'];
    if($node->type == "article" && isset($build['field_pdf']['#items']))
    {
        $build['field_pdf']['#items'][0]['#file']->filename = t('PDF Version');
    }
}
```

OR

```
function yourmodule_node_view_alter(&$build)
{
    $node = $build['#node'];
    if($node->type == "article" && isset($build['field_pdf']['#items']))
    {
        hide($build['field_pdf']);
        $build['my_themed_link']['#markup'] = l(t('PDF Version'), file_build_uri($build['field_pdf']['#items'][0]['uri']));
        $build['my_themed_link']['#weight'] = 10;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested that yet, hope it works for you.

Muhammad

Comment: Missed it by *that* much!!  (Channeling Get Smart for a moment.)

Comment: Changed your first bit of code just slightly.  Had to modify this value instead:  `$build['field_pdf'][0]['#file']->filename = t('PDF Version)`  -- Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the description field enabled for the PDF upload field you should be able to access that variable with the print_r statement.

The you could write something like this:

```
<a href="<?php print render($content['field_pdf']['path'])?>"><?php print render($content['field_pdf']['description']);?></a>
```

This code is not exactly what drupal uses, but you can grab the correct array format from using the code below in your node.tpl.php file.

```
<pre><?php print_r($node); ?></pre>
```